# Spacing in axis label when using expression(paste(...))

Tags: r, axis-labels, plotmath

Consider the following example:

```
plot(c(2,4,6)~c(1,2,3),xlab="x",
ylab=expression(paste('flux (g ',CO[2]~m^{-2}~h^{-1},')')))
```

Obviously I want a full space between "g" and "CO", but for some reason I get a smaller (with some labels even zero) space in the graph label.

The problem is even more obvious, if I do it like this:

```
plot(c(2,4,6)~c(1,2,3),xlab="x",
ylab=expression(paste('flux (g C',O[2]~m^{-2}~h^{-1},')')))
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to fix the spacing or even a better way to create labels with lots of sub/superscripts and greek letters?

Comment: is `ylab=expression("flux"~(g~CO[2]~m^{-2}~h^{-1})))` better? (meaning: why do you use paste?)

Comment: no, it's not better because then the space after flux is too small.

Comment: dunno, it seems to me that the spacing is correct. Try telling us your OS, graphics device, and a screenshot. Also, see if the following shows increasing spacing: `library(grid) ; grid.text(expression(flux*(g~CO[2]~m^{-2}~h^{-1}), flux~(g~CO[2]~m^{-2}~h^{-1}), flux~~(g~CO[2]~m^{-2}~h^{-1})), y=unit(0.5,"npc") + unit(0:2,"lines"))`

Comment: platform       x86_64-pc-mingw32            
arch           x86_64                       
os             mingw32                      
system         x86_64, mingw32              
status                                      
major          2                            
minor          15.0                         
year           2012                         
month          03                           
day            30                           
svn rev        58871                        
language       R                            
version.string R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)

Comment: The second one works fine. It seems one should avoid mixing character-strings and an expression. It's a nuisance if the string is a bit longer.

Comment: I don't see any difference between `"flux "*(g~CO[2]~m^{-2}~h^{-1})` and `flux~(g~CO[2]~m^{-2}~h^{-1})` on a quartz device

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In all likelihood you *are* getting a typographically correct "space",  in the font your OS uses for non-serif display. You can change fonts  or you can insert blank space that is sufficient to hold a particular character string with plotmath `phantom()`:

```
 plot(c(2,4,6)~c(1,2,3),xlab="x",
     ylab=expression(paste('flux',phantom(x),'(g ',CO[2]~m^{-2}~h^{-1},')')))
```

Or as @baptiste points out this can be done without plomath `paste` using ordinary plotmath separators because a tilde in a true R expression gets handled as a "space":

```
     ylab=expression(flux*phantom(x)*(g~CO[2]~m^{-2}~h^{-1})))
```