# How can spaces be added to parsed labels in ggplot annotations?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a weird little problem. I want to label some plots with the units of the variables, but if I add spaces to the label, I get an error.

For example, this chunk returns a nice superscripted character:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = c(1:10), y = c(1:10))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = -Inf, y = Inf, hjust = -1, vjust = 1.1,
           label = "a**2", parse = TRUE)
```

However, if I add a space to the label, eg:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = -Inf, y = Inf, hjust = -1, vjust = 1.1,
           label = "Some words and a**2", parse = TRUE)
```

I get:

```
Error in `annotate()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `parse()`:
! <text>:1:6: unexpected symbol
1: Some words
```

**Does anyone have a solution to create labels with both spaces and superscripts?**

Comment: When using `plotmath` use a `~` to get a space, i.e. do `"Some~words~and~a**2"`

Comment: Possible dups: [Superscripting in ggplot2 using plotmath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880053/superscripting-in-ggplot2-using-plotmath) or [Spacing in axis label when using expression(paste(...))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716374/spacing-in-axis-label-when-using-expressionpaste)

Comment: Possible dup, but the use of ~ for spaces only works in the example I provided; in a more complex label with additional symbols and numbers, I still get errors. The solution @dahj provides below works for my actual label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is caused by using parse = TRUE, which leads the annotate() function to expect the label to be in mathematical notation, which your plaintext in the second example breaks.

As per the [R Graphics Cookbook](https://r-graphics.org/recipe-annotate-text-math), an overall helpful resource, the way to mix regular text into the annotation and have it show properly is to use the opposite type of quotes to mark the plaintext part - so in your case, as you used

```
label = "Some words and a**2"
```

we would add single quotes around the plaintext part, then add an asterisk * to properly show them next to each other, ending up with:

```
label = "'Some words and '*a**2"
```

Which yields the result you describe as desirable.

Comment: Great, this works. One issue: in the actual script, I want to bold the label, but it doesn't seem to work with the superscript. Any idea if there's a workaround?

Comment: @jsgraydon I have to say I am not aware of a workaround while still working with annotate(); if you don't have an awful lot of labels, I would probably opt for  

`geom_text(x = -Inf, y = Inf, hjust = -1, vjust = 1.1, label = "'Some words and '*a^2", parse = TRUE, fontface = "bold")`  

as geom_text works with bolding without any hiccups.

Comment: That actually didn't work for my real label. Wondering if the inclusion of other symbols and numbers somehow caused issues? I can work around it, but it's an annoying limitation.